# How to display floating button over webview on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-webview

can't display floating button over webview on android.
ios work fine, on android doesn't show.

**render function:**

```
         <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{position:'absolute',right:0,marginTop:90,marginRight:10,zIndex:1,height:50,width:50}}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.addButton}
                                underlayColor='#ff7043' onPress={()=>{console.log('pressed')}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 50, color: 'black'}}>+</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <WebView
            source={require('./index.html')}
            style={{marginTop:0}}
             scalesPageToFit={Platform.OS !== 'ios'}
            onMessage={this.onMessage}
            postMessage={"Hello from RN"}
        />
    </View>
```

**css:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    addButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff5722',
        borderColor: '#ff5722',
        borderWidth: 1,
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 20,
        right:20,
        shadowColor: "#000000",
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        shadowOffset: {
            height: 1,
            width: 0
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

How can I display a button over web view on android ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, put the Button View code **under/after** the WebView code

```
<View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <WebView
            source={require('./index.html')}
            style={{marginTop:0}}
             scalesPageToFit={Platform.OS !== 'ios'}
            onMessage={this.onMessage}
            postMessage={"Hello from RN"}
        />
        <View style={{position:'absolute',right:0,marginTop:90,marginRight:10,zIndex:1,height:50,width:50}}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.addButton}
                                    underlayColor='#ff7043' onPress={()=>{console.log('pressed')}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 50, color: 'black'}}>+</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
</View>
```

If for some reason you can't put it under the WebView, adding a **elevation** style prop higher than the WebView's, alongside the zIndex style prop will work for you.

Comment: thank you so much (:
can you please explain to me why its work like this on android?

Comment: zIndex is quite buggy at android, it's better to code in the (reverse) order you want your elements to appear, since elevation puts a shadow which you might don't want to have in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `zIndex` property is quite broken on Android (see [the dedicated issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20zindex)). To compensate for it, you must invert the rendering order of your container's children.

This can be done either by rendering the button **after** the `WebView`:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <WebView />
    <View style={{ styles.button }} />
</View>
```

Or by reversing the display order in your container, using `flexDirection`:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }}>
    <View style={{ styles.button }} />
    <WebView />
</View>
```

Note that you can also use the android-specific [`elevation` API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewstyleproptypes.html#elevation). This will act as a reliable z-index and is the only way to display a shadow on Android.